# Overlapping sound in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, overlap

Okay, so I am making a game, and I can't figure out how to keep the sound track from overlapping. When the game comes to a lose or win screen, I will click "Play again" and the sound will overlap. I have the sound on it's own layer. Here's what I have so far.

```
var snd_SolidState = new SolidState();
snd_SolidState.play(0,1);
```

And on Layer 2 Frame 2 and 3, I have:

```
snd_SolidState.stop();
snd_SolidState = null;
```

It says "stop" is not a function. So how would I get the song to stop on the lose/win screens? SolidState is the song.

If the code is related to the click of the "Play again" Button, here is the code for those.

```
mc_again.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upAgain);
function upAgain(e:MouseEvent){
gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable *snd_SolidState* is a **Sound** object, **Sound** doesn't have a *stop* method implemented; The **Sound**.play() however, returns a **SoundChannel** object which does...

So you can store that (the **SoundChannel** object returned by *snd_SolidState.play()*), which you can later use to stop the song.

**PS:** I recommend you start typing your variables (ie: *var snd_SolidState:Sound;*), that way you force yourself to know which object type you're dealing with and can find reference for it; in this case [Sound.play()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play()).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a SoundChannel to stop your music.